# Attempted to call method "createQueryBuilder" on class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity "Vehicules" that have ManyToOne relation with the entity "User". So each User hav one or more vehicules. I'm trying to count the number of vehicules foreach user and trying to show it in a table .
this is a part of my entity Vehicule

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OC\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE") 
     */
    protected $direction;
```

this is the function in which i want to count the number of vehicules foreach user (direction) and show it in a table

```
public function afficheAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine();
        $demandes = $em->getRepository('DemandevehBundle:Demande')->findAll();
        // trying to count the number of vehicules foreach direction     
        $vehicules = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CarPfeBundle:Vehicule')->findAll();
       foreach($vehicules as $vehicule) {
        $qb = $vehicule->createQueryBuilder('v');
        $qb->select('count(v.id)');
        $qb->where('v.direction = ?1');
        $qb->setParameter('1', $vehicule->getId());
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $result = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
        return $result;
       }
       // fin
        return $this->render('DemandevehBundle:Demande:affiche.html.twig', array('demandes' => $demandes
                    ,'result' => $result));
    }
```

I get this error

```
Attempted to call method "createQueryBuilder" on class "Car\PfeBundle\Entity\Vehicule".
```

I feel that my function make no sense that's why i get this error. Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Is possible to create a query builder on an entity manager instead of an entity. So you use the relative manager of the class so try this:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()
     ->getRepository('CarPfeBundle:Vehicule')
     ->createQueryBuilder('v');
```

instead of this:

```
    $qb = $vehicule->createQueryBuilder('v');
```

Hope this help

Comment: Actually i'm confused how could it help. To be more specefic i tried that for just one variable so i've changed "$vehicule->getId()" to "5" it works but i want to get it for all my vehicules how could i do that?